# How to click image on column to edit text on other columns on the same row?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, web

How to click image on column to edit text on other columns on the same row?

This is the form that has to be done before a row is added to the table

```
 <form id="myForm" method="post" action="javascript:void(0);" target="_parent">

        <p>Name: 
          <input type="text" name="Name" value="" maxlength="200" size="60">
        </p>

        <p>User ID:
            <input type="text" name="UserID" value="" maxlength="200" size="60">
        </p>

        <p>Password:
            <input type="password" name="Password" value="" maxlength="200" size="60">
        </p>

        <p>Organization:
            <input type="text" name="Organization" value="" maxlength="200" size="60">
        </p>

        <p> Role:
          <select name="Role">
            <option name = "Member" selected>Member</option>
            <option name = "Admin">Admin</option>
          </select>
        </p><br />
        <p> 
          <input type="submit" name="submit" id="submit" value="Submit" onClick="closebox()">
          <input type="button" name="cancel" value="Cancel" onClick="closebox()">
        </p>
      </form>
```

This is my Jquery function that adds a row into the table

```
$('#submit').on('click',function(){
    var st = '';
    $('#myForm input[type=text],input[type=password],select').each(function(){
        st = st+ '<td>'+$(this).val()+'</td>';
        $(this).val('');
    });
    st = st+ '<td class="status">Active</td><td><img class="pencil" src="images/pencil-black.png"></img><img class="lock" src="images/lock-black.png"></img><img class="bin" src="images/bin-black.png"></img></td>';
    $('#tablelist').append('<tr>'+st+'</tr>');
});
```

The image I want to click is under the the img class, pencil. However the problem I am having is that I do not know how I am going to be able to select the column which i want to edit because I am not able to give it a class based on the row adding function i am using.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is the working DEMO http://jsfiddle.net/yeyene/xc5dT/1/

In case you need delete and lock, I also added in these functions.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$('#submit').on('click',function(){
    var st = '';
    $('#myForm input[type=text],input[type=password],select').each(function(){
        st = st+ '<td>'+$(this).val()+'</td>';
        $(this).val('');
    });
    st = st+ '<td class="status">Active</td><td><img class="pencil" src="http://cdn2.iconfinder.com/data/icons/diagona/icon/16/019.png" /><img class="lock" src="http://cdn4.iconfinder.com/data/icons/sketchdock-ecommerce-icons/log-in.png" /><img class="bin" src="http://cdn2.iconfinder.com/data/icons/aspneticons_v1.0_Nov2006/trash_16x16.gif" /></td>';
    $('#tablelist').append('<tr>'+st+'</tr>');
});

$(document).on('click','.pencil',function(){
    for(var i=0; i<5; i++){
        var val = $(this).parent().siblings('td').eq(i).text();
        $(this).parent().siblings('td').eq(i).html('<input type="text" width="50" value="'+val+'" />');
    }
});

$(document).on('click','.lock',function(){
    for(var i=0; i<5; i++){
        var val = $(this).parent().siblings('td').eq(i).find('input').val();
        $(this).parent().siblings('td').eq(i).html(val);
    }
});    

$(document).on('click','.bin',function(){
    $(this).parent().parent('tr').remove();
});

});
```

Comment: +1 for this! I was going to suggest dynamically giving the first `<td>` a name, then name+1, name+2 etc etc... but your way is a lot cleaner and does exactly what OP wanted. Thanks.

Comment: How do i get rid of the textbox after im done editing?For some reason i cannot shorten the box even when im configuring the width too. Thanks btw!

Comment: check my update answer again, after you amend, click lock icon, it will remove the input box, and for the width, just use this css... #tablelist input {width:50px;}